# Singular homology but only considering linear simplices $[v_0,...,v_n]$ is isomorphic to singular homology?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

There is a homology theory of open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ defined as singular homology but instead of considering all maps $\sigma:\Delta^n \rightarrow U$ as simplices, we only consider the linear ones $\sigma = [v_0,...,v_n]$.

What is this homology called and where can I find a proof that it is isomorphic to singular homology?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find this "special singular homology theory"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Some book or pdf about algebraic topology. Sorry I can't be more helpful but that's all I can remember.

Comment: PL manifolds have a simplicial homology where the simplicial chains can be "arbitrarily fine", ie it is not restricted to some special triangulisation. I think also here its just called simplicial homology.

Comment: Reviewing Kirwan and Woolf, they do call this construction simplicial homology (defined on page 18 of the second edition).

Comment: @s.harp add this as an answer and I'll accept it